# Drag and Drop Upload not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, input, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a drag and drop to upload functionality with ondragover and ondrop functions.

```js
dropContainer.ondragover=dropContainer.ondragenter=function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
};
dropContainer.ondrop=function(evt) { 
   if(evt.dataTransfer.files.length <= 1){
      wpUploadFile.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
      evt.preventDefault();
   } else {
      alert("Please upload only one file.");
      evt.preventDefault();
   }
};
```

```html
<input type='file' id='wpUploadFile'></input>
 
<div id='dropContainer' style='border: dashed 0.5px;border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;border-top-left-radius: 14px;background: #f9f9f9;text-align: center;padding: 6px;padding-bottom: 10px;width:600px'>
   <p id='dropContainerP'style='color:grey; font-size: 14px;padding: 2px;'>Drag And Drop File To Upload</p>
   <img src='cloud-upload1.png' style='height: 36px;margin-top: -23px;'></img>
</div>
```

I want that when i drag and drop a file to dropContainer, the file should be assigned to wpUploadFile (input type file) as well.
This code is working fine chrome but not on mozilla.
chrome version: 66.0.3359.139
mozilla firefox version: 65.0

Please help providing a solution to make it work on firefox as well.

Comment: It's working in Mozilla on my machine

Comment: Which version of Mozilla you are using?

Comment: Drag and drop appears to be working fine for me (Firefox 65.0). I suggest you open your browser console and check for other errors.

Comment: Cannot reproduce

Comment: this code is working fine on (Firefox 62.0)....

Comment: Not Working on Safari 12.0.3